# How to increase the font size in propotion to view height

Tags: ios, fonts, ios-autolayout

I am increase Textview height in propotion to parent view but font size remains same.

I would like to change the font size accoring to textview or screen size so it fills up the space in textview

The problem I am facing is in iPhone 4s it fills up the space while iphone 7s there are lots of empty space

is there any constraint we can use to achieve that other than doing programtically.

Comment: Pretty sure you have to do that via code, not constraints.

Comment: It'd be really good if its via constraints as we can see in real time on various devices

Comment: You're talking about an editable UITextView, right? Not a UILabel? Generally, a UITextView is used to display and edit large amounts of text, including allowing the text to scroll. Trying to auto-size the font to make the text view fill an area goes against the whole purpose of using the UITextView.

Comment: yes I am using UItextView ... how can I  increase the font size t fill up the the heights in view

Comment: textview is not editable

Comment: OK - rather confusing... by default, a UITextView is editable, and scrollable. If you are not going to allow edit or scroll, why are you using a UITextView?

Comment: I just want to show block of text in the view controller in label its difficult right... for more text .. textview is right I believe

Comment: If you use a UILabel, you can set the font size to very large, and set a minimum font size or font scale. That way it *will* auto-size to fit the area.

Comment: Oh is it ! You mean to say ... I can give 5 lines of text and it will try to increase it size .to fit the all lines ..Am i right ? you can answer ... this to post ...I will see if it works ..I will accept it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `UILabel` instead of a `UITextView`, you can set the Font Size to very large, with a small `Minimum Font Scale`. Then, your text will "auto-size" to fit the view.

In this example, the Font is set to `System 100.0` --- really, really big. `Autoshrink` is set to `Minimum Font Scale` with a value of `0.1` - or, 1/10th of 100, which is 10, and that's probably as small as you would want it to get.

While designing your view in Interface Builder, you *will* see the font size change as you change the size of the view.

[image]

Comment: do we have to set number of lines ?

Comment: Yes, Number of Lines = 0

Comment: Ok is it possible that I can do the same thing for button as well... becuase I want the button to have same font height as labels

Comment: Perhaps you should show what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for ... pointing out the truncate tail and autoshrink .. helped me a lot... saved my day

Comment: Basically i want all the font size to be same ... like two labels and one buttons... font size seems different ...u got any idea on how to solve this plz

Comment: What you are describing sounds unusual... I'd suggest you layout the elements in IB how you want it to look, and post an image here. You started with "a textview on 4s and 7" and now it's two labels and one button. Tough to help if we don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh the thing is that ... I have replaced those textview with labels... i had set labels height in propotion to views height ... so labels fotn size changes according to label height... if two labels are having different heights then font size seems different among them... then there is button .. whose font size also seems different.. so is it possible that all the two label and buttons font size is uniform